# Laravel Query Builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, query-builder

I have some trouble with Laravel Query Builder.
I want to convert this SQL Query:

```
SELECT ItemNo, Description_DEU AS DescDE, Description_ENG AS DescEN, Description_FRA AS DescFR, Description_ESP AS DescES, Description_ITA AS DescIT, PriceId, Quantity, PricePerItem, PriceSheet_Id AS SheetId 
FROM articles 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM price WHERE PriceSheet_Id = :$variable) AS filteredPrices 
ON articles.ItemNo = filteredPrices.ItemNumber
```

I tried doing the following:

```
$results = DB::table('articles')
    ->select('ItemNo', 'Description_DEU', 'Description_ENG', 'Description_FRA', 'Description_ESP', 'Description_ITA', 'PriceId', 'Quantity', 'PricePerItem', 'PriceSheet_Id')
    ->leftJoin(DB::raw('SELECT * FROM price AS filteredPrices'), function($join) {
            $join->on('articles.ItemNo', '=', 'filteredPrices.ItemNumber');
    })
    ->where('PriceSheet_Id', '=', $var)
    ->get();
```

But It still tells me that I have a syntax error somewhere. Any help would be appreciated.

Error MSG := SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT * FROM price AS filteredPrices on `articles`.`ItemNo` = `filteredPrices`.' at line 1 (SQL: select `ItemNo`, `Description_DEU`, `Description_ENG`, `Description_FRA`, `Description_ESP`, `Description_ITA`, `PriceId`, `Quantity`, `PricePerItem`, `PriceSheet_Id` from `articles` left join SELECT * FROM price AS filteredPrices on `articles`.`ItemNo` = `filteredPrices`.`ItemNumber` where `PriceSheet_Id` = 1)

Comment: what syntax error are you getting ?

Comment: Maybe you should try put `->toSql()` at the end, and `dd()` that. That'll give you the raw SQL query and you can see what it's constructing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To build the SQL query provided you should put the where condition in the raw subquery, and alias the subquery to reference it in the ON:

```
$results = DB::table('articles')
    ->select('ItemNo', 'Description_DEU', 'Description_ENG', 'Description_FRA', 'Description_ESP', 'Description_ITA', 'PriceId', 'Quantity', 'PricePerItem', 'PriceSheet_Id')
    ->leftJoin(DB::raw('(SELECT * FROM price AS filteredPrices WHERE PriceSheet_Id = ' . $var .') as filteredPrices'), function($join) 
    {
        $join->on('articles.ItemNo', '=', 'filteredPrices.ItemNumber');
    })
    ->get();
```

Comment: however, the syntax error was due to the missing parenthesis in the subquery

Comment: which one do you mean?

Comment: The SQL syntax error was caused by the missing parenthesis around `SELECT * FROM price AS filteredPrices WHERE PriceSheet_Id = ' . $var .'`